# php with readline support compiled for windows

Tags: php, windows, compilation, read-eval-print-loop

Is there any compiled php package with readline support built-in?

readline is required in order to use php in interactive mode.

I looked at how to compile php for windows but they require MS Visual Studio which I don't have.

Answer (score 5):

[Readline](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.readline.php) extension is not available on Windows. I think it is possible to compile PHP under cygwin enabling `--with-readline` option

Comment: The question I've been asking for years is, *why* is this basic, essential function not available on Windows? If the OS offers nothing equivalent, surely you could emulate it.

Comment: Five years later, from PHP v7.1 readline is now available on Windows

Comment: year 2023, `function_exists("readline_callback_handler_install")` is false, but `function_exists("readline")` is true. meaning no asynchronity which is the main reason to use it

Answer (score 3):

```
    //The readline library is not available on Windows.

<?php
       if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT') {
           echo '$ ';
           $line = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1024, PHP_EOL);
        } else {
                 $line = readline('$ ');
               }
 ?>
```

I found this code straight out of the php documentation. As you may see there is no support for the readline library in windows machines (at least in a ddefault packet) which sucks but you can get something similar by doing the "$line = blah, blah " you see in the code above.

I tried it and made it work using window's standard cmd (althought I think the interactive php mode won't work in windows no matter what) but It's better than not having any user input (if you actually get to remember all that code).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit late, but here's the solution that solved this problem for me: In style of C#'s `Console`, I wrote a little class that can do a `readLine()` as well as a `writeLine($str)`:

```
class Console {
    const READLINE_MAX_LENGTH = 0xFFFF;
    const WRITELINE_NEWLINE = "\n";

    private static /*Resource*/ $stdin;
    private static /*Resource*/ $stdout;

    public static function /*void*/ close () {
        fclose(self::$stdin);
        fclose(self::$stdout);
    }

    public static function /*void*/ open () {
        self::$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
        self::$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
    }

    public static function /*string*/ readLine () {
        return stream_get_line(self::$stdin, self::READLINE_MAX_LENGTH, "\r\n");
    }

    public static function /*void*/ writeLine (/*string*/ $str) {
        fwrite(self::$stdout, $str);
        fwrite(self::$stdout, self::WRITELINE_NEWLINE);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Console::open();
echo "Input something: ";

$str = Console::readLine();
if (is_string($str))
    Console::writeLine($str);
else
    echo "ERROR";

Console::close();
```

---

**EDIT:** This method obviously only works, if the parent process doesn't change STDOUT or STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the answer from galymzhan, another option to run PHP in interactive mode on Windows would be to use one of the PHP REPLs. You wont get tab completion, since that relies on readline.

The REPL that has worked for me so far is PHP-Shell

http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/php-shell/

Comment: Website is now down :(